# Simplexml How to access all element of the same node

Tags: simplexml

```
[Villa] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [VillaID] => 6
                [VillaName] => Mary
                [Distances] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [Distance] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [Destination] => Sea
                                        [Value] => 1000 m
                                    )

                                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [Destination] => Market
                                        [Value] => 800 m
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )

        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [VillaID] => 21
                [VillaName] => Marion
                [Distances] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [Distance] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [Destination] => Beach
                                        [Value] => 5 min
                                    )

                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

I need to print all, only of 1 villa (example with id = 6) but VillaId is not an array so it's impossible to get all with foreach

I can obtain it with:
echo 'Name of Villa: '.$xml->Villa[0]->VillaName.'
'; 
etc. etc ... but in this way have to change manually for every villa (too much) the value in the brackets. 
i've tried with $xml->Villa[$value]->VillaName; ($value comes from another page) but it's not working...
Tanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question starts with *"i have this xml:"* followed by something that is *not* XML. I'm not saying this to be a smartass, rather because it's important for XML beginners to understand that `print_r()` is *not* the right way to inspect `SimpleXMLElement`s. Sometimes it will show you things that aren't in your XML, other times it will not show things that are actually in your XML. In short: **do not use `print_r()` on SimpleXMLElement**. Just use `->asXML()` and look at the actual XML.

From what I understand, you want to locate and *select* a node based on some criteria. XML just happens to have a language for that: [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). The official specs aren't terribly user-friendly but [w3schools.com has a pretty good XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp).

> I need to print all, only of 1 villa (example with id = 6) but VillaId is not an array so it's impossible to get all with foreach

Anywhere in your document, you want to select all `Villa` nodes with an attribute `VillaID` whose value is `"6"`. In XPath:

```
//Villa[@VillaID="6"]
```

Via SimpleXML:

```
$xml->xpath('//Villa[@VillaID="6"]');
```

Attention, [`xpath()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) always return an array.